# Perl is it possible to combine 2 if statements?

Tags: perl

So right now this is what I have:

```
if ($stuff =~ /^(bad|alsobad)$/) {
print "Seems incorrect";
exit 0;
}
```

Is it somehow possible to have something like this?

```
    if ($stuff =~ /^(bad|alsobad)$/){
#
    if ($twostuff =~ /^(nan|na)$/) {
    print "Seems incorrect";
    exit 0;
    }
#
    }
```

Comment: Sure, why not? Did you try it?

Comment: Yeah, that should work.  You can also use `&&`, which might be more useful if you end up needing an `else` clause that applies to both conditions together.

Comment: @theglauber No actually have not... I kinda though about adding the {} only as I was writing this...

Comment: The simplest way to answer your question is to run your code and try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code:

```
if ($stuff =~ /^(bad|alsobad)$/){
    if ($twostuff =~ /^(nan|na)$/) {
        print "Seems incorrect";
        exit 0;
    }
}
```

... should work just fine. An alternative would be:

```
if ( $stuff =~ /^(bad|alsobad)$/ and $twostuff =~ /^(nan|na)$/ ){
    print "Seems incorrect";
    exit 0;
}
```